# yii dropdownList same value for display?

Tags: drop-down-menu, yii

my predecessor in the project didn't save drop down list values in a table; they were in the html file...The guy also didn't use `$form->dropdownList()` to create the selects...

Of course I had now huge problems for pre-selecting values on editing; thus I changed all `<select>` to `$form->dropdownList()`.

But now I have a different problem, as

```
echo $form->dropdownList($model,'location',
        array("Art","Gallery","Bar","Club"));
```

Now produces integer values for the DB...

I know I can set the display value like so:
array("Art" => "Art")....
but I would rather like to avoid that - there are a bunch of views displaying the value directly... :(

Is there a way to tell yii that the DB values shall be the same as the display value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override `dropDownList` method of `CActiveForm` widget as follows:

```
<?php
class ActiveForm extends CActiveForm
{
    public $valuesAsKeys = false;

    public function dropDownList($model,$attribute,$data,$htmlOptions=array())
    {
        if (!$this->valuesAsKeys)
            return parent::dropDownList($model, $attribute, $data, $htmlOptions);

        $newData = array();
        foreach ($data as $value)
            $newData[$value] = $value;
        return parent::dropDownList($model, $attribute, $newData, $htmlOptions);
    }
}
```

and then use it like this:

```
<?php
$form = $this->beginWidget("application.components.ActiveForm", array(
    'valuesAsKeys' => true,
    // other parameters here
));

// Rendering form's elements here
$this->endWidget();
```

Comment: @Harry B's answer is more appropriate.

Answer (score 6):

If the array values are unique (Yii requires unique keys), you can use...

```
$data = array("Art","Gallery","Bar","Club");
echo $form->dropdownList($model,'location', array_combine($data, $data));
```

`array_combine` will use the same data for both the keys and values of the listdata.

Answer (score 0):

Harry B's answer works great, thanks! In my case, I wanted to use custom option values and also include a prompt, so to expand upon his example, I created a method that returned an array of keys and values. The keys array started with 'prompt' and the 'values' array started with '(select)' and then I looped over my data source and added each key to the keys array and each value to the values array. My code was a bit more complicated, involving regexes, but here's the basic gist:

```
// Controller method popupRowListValues($source)
$displayKeys = array('prompt');
$displayValues = array('select');

foreach ($source as $key=>$value) {
    $displayKeys[] = $key;
    $displayValues = $value;
}

// View
$displayList = $this->popupRowListValues($source);

echo $form->dropDownListRow($model, $column_name, array_combine(
    $displayList['displayKeys'], $displayList['displayValues']
));
```